# How can I add in-code annotations in PR reviews usign Github's `gh` tool?

Tags: github, pull-request, review, github-cli

On the Github web UI, I can click on a line and say something like:

> Good architecture, but please pass the `std::vector<std::uint8_t> hugedata` as `const &`, to avoid a copy.

and bundle such comments as one review with a final verdict.

So far, I've only found `gh pr review`, which only allows me to generally approve/comment/reject a PR that I'm reviewing.

- Is there a way to do detailed in-code reviews using the `gh` CLI?
- if not, how can I use the github api to do that myself?

Comment: Rest api supports this directly (https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/reviews): note, that json comment object has fields for "target path" as well as "target line range", apart from the obvious "body". `gh` tool may not implement it just yet, but it is definitely doable with some cli flags or body markdown tags (`gh` is calling the same rest api).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gh` doesn't seem to have built in support for this, but you can still use `gh api` to call the API:

1. Note the repository owner, repository name, and pull request ID
2. Get a diff of the pull request so you can get the right files and positions

```
gh api -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.diff" /repos/OWNER/REPO/pulls/ID
```

3. Note any files you want to comment on after `+++`
4. Note any positions you want to comment on after `@@` (by number of lines after that line)
5. Create a pull request review with your comments (using the file as `path`, the line offset from the start of the hunk as `position`, and your commend as `body`)

```
echo '{ "comments": [{"path": ...,"position": ...,"body": ...}, ...] }' |
  gh api -X POST /repos/OWNER/REPO/pulls/ID/reviews
```

6. Submit the pull request review on GitHub (alternatively if you want to automate this, add the `body` and `event` properties to your review's body)

Comment: My `gh api` (current from .. sigh .. brew) does not support `-d`, but piping into `gh api --method=POST <url>` seems to work (`echo '<json>' | gh api <...>`).

Comment: (the `-d` might be a copy/pasty from using cURL)

Comment: I'm not sure where I got `-d`, but it's not working with the latest version (2.30.0), so I've edited this to include a pipe.

Comment: Did you try that the pipe works? I might be mistaken. One thing works consistently here: specifying the payload in a file (and pass  `--input`).